# Are questions about payment service terms and conditions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I received an updated terms and conditions for the automatic payments system for my Auto & Home Insurance carrier. I would like to ask a question about it, but the question really boils down to:

- Can a provider absolve themselves of liability for their own gross negligence?
- Is it even legal for them to suggest they aren't liable for protecting 'customer data?
- The updated terms suggest that if I don't immediately withdraw from their service, I have given implicit consent to the updated terms. I think a payment posted on schedule while this notice was in the mail or in my mailbox, so is it too late to withdraw my consent?
- If my identity or personal information is stolen after they are breached, do I have any recourse at all if I "agree" to the terms and conditions?

These questions are primarily legal-based, so I'm expecting that they're off topic for this SE. Is there any other site I can ask questions about T&C or EULAs on?

Comment: Did you know there is a new http://law.stackexchange.com site in beta?

Comment: I did *not* know. Thank you so much for pointing that out! Their help articles are pretty sparse, but I suppose it can't hurt to take a crack over there. @ChrisW.Rea